# Cron/Anacron vs. Systemd

Tags: cron, systemd, anacron, scheduler

Linux provides three different job schedulers i.e. Cron, Anacron and Systemd-Timer. What are the benefits of Cron/Anacron vs. Systemd-Timer?

Answer (score 9):

### In favor of Cron

- A simple one line entry /etc/crontab and your job is set to run

### In favor of systemd

- Consistent run time environment with the same environment variable set. This solves a common problem with Cron jobs: They run fine in one environment and not via cron because different PATH or other values in the environment.
- Better logging! `systemd` captures STDOUT and STDERR of your job and stores it in the systemd journal.
- Better job status. You can use `systemctl status your-service` to check the status of what you ran. Outside of combing logs, cron offers no structured way to query the service status.
- Better timer status. Use `systemctl list-timers` to get a summary of enabled timers and see when they last ran and when they will next run.

### In summary

Systemd timers have some overhead to learn and setup, but provide a number of benefits. There some packages like `systemd-cron` and `systemd-cron-next` that allow you to have `cron` entries converted to `systemd-timers`, to try to provide a best-of-both-worlds solution